# Create share inside another share in Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share

What is the proper way for creation a share inside another? I need to share subdirectory of share to another division (**div2**). And I have to secure it from change name of this directory by **div1**... Finally it should looks like that:

- `\\ad\share` [`d:\share`, belongs to **div1**]
- `\\ad\subshare` [`d:\share\subdir`, belongs to **div2**; **div1** has write permission, but cannot change dir name (`\\ad\share\subdir`)]

I tried to make symbolic link to

```
PS> cmd /c mklink /D D:\subshare \\ad\share\subdir\
```

and create share `subshare` on this link. Not working

Next I tried create share `subshare` and make symlink inside `share`

```
PS> cmd /c mklink /D D:\share\subdir \\ad\subshare\
```

Not working.

I could share the subdir directly, but is this the only way? I don't want to do that because I will not see it in main disk directory of shares and I'm affraid to broke permissions in the future.

That's why I ask for the proper way. :)

Comment: Why do you want multiple shares? This seems to be a simple permissions problem.

Comment: Commercial Dept shares documents to other depts in company. Is there any special permissions to symlinks? Because in the second example only symlink doesn't work.

Comment: I don't see why you need symlinks at all. You only need to set proper permissions on the directories.

Comment: I want to have all shares in one directory and links in Commercial Dept' share. For example **div1** has share **invoices**. Commercial Dept has main share **Invoices** and there **div1_invoices**, **div2_invoices**...

Comment: This is a poor way to do this. Either use different shares at the same level or use one share and enable ABE in combination with NTFS permissions to secure the folders.

Comment: @joeqwerty In your scenario I should map for Commercial Dept 20 extra shares (div19_invoices). One for each dept. What if depts will be 40? ;)

Comment: Why do these need to be independent shares? Why not create a few parent level shares and then create department level folders under the appropriate shares? Using NTFS and ABE will allow you to secure and make visible the appropriate folders to the appropriate people. This is how most companies structure their shared folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that when I use `mklink /J` instead `mklink /D` I've got exactly what I wanted to.

With one another problem (acceptable for now) in that share:

- user* can create
- user can delete
- but **user can't rename** files or directories: error 0x80071128

*user with Full control permissions